# Where are io.elementary.music settings file?

Tags: settings, music

So... Unintentionally I put the music folder as the system folder and now it takes forever to scan, even by it gets into a loop when it starts to scan the /dev folder, so I've been looking for ways to set the music folder without opening the application, or reset application settings

Note: user-dirs.dirs don't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `gconf-editor`.

If not installed do `sudo apt install dconf-editor`, open the app (you'll find it in `Applications -> System` menu) and go to `io.elementary.music.settings` where you can find the `music-floder` key which you can then change manually.